# Access 2010 remove access window completely

Tags: ms-access

I found a question here on stack overflow about removing the access window and they displayed a picture showing it done, but when I attempted to use the code it didn't do anything as far as I can tell.  When it comes to VB and Access I'm a newb and could use a little help in getting my database to display something similar to this.  http://img403.imageshack.us/img403/2053/pycsd.png

Comment: Obviously, your code didn't do all the things Albert's code did. We can't tell you what you messed up unless we see your code.

Answer (score 0):

That is one of my screen caps. All you need in your startup code is the following line of code:

```
 DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
```

The above code can be placed in your startup form.

So, the general settings are:
Tabbed window mode (which is default anyway).
Turn off display of tabs.
Turn off navigation pane.

Just set the form as your startup form and in the forms on-load event execute the above one line of code.